# Unity3d Imported trees wind zone not working

Tags: unity-game-engine, tree

Does anyone know if I upload trees created in Blender or 3DS max? For example, why can I not use the wind and do not move the leaves?

Comment: Have you read this? https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/terrain-Trees.html it should guide you with wind zones on custom trees.

Comment: I believe for custom trees that are not made in the SpeedTree editor you need to add a custom shader and make a second UV map that the wind zone can interact with to simulate a "bending" effect. See here: https://forum.unity.com/threads/use-wind-gameobject-in-custom-mesh-and-shader.474759/

Answer (score 0):

Custom tree meshes can be used, they just need a bit more work.

It would be relatively easy to add a hinge constraint and apply the wind force directly on the tree mesh, but the tree would simply pivot around the hinge, and not bend as expected.

The built-in trees use geometry shaders to mutate the tree mesh using the wind forces. You would need to apply the same shaders to your tree to make the geometry bend, instead of just swinging.

The Unity Asset Store has a number of plugins available:

[Advanced Terrain Shaders v2 (Free)](https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/2680)

[Custom Tree Importer extension which can simplify importing custom tree meshes (Paid)](https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/21079)

Another workaround for a simple tree might be to use a character rig on the tree body, and use particles for the leaves / branches. This would be computationally expensive, and difficult to modify.

Comment: While this is technically a solution, creating a custom shader for something this simple wouldn't be terribly difficult, and most likely would be the most efficient way to achieve this. Just hook the Unity Wind Zone's wind velocity vector up to a "_Wind" float4 in your shader and watch the magic happen (:

Comment: @BrandonMiller Sure! I just have little experience with shaders so I couldn't answer in that regard. Why not post an answer with an example of the custom shader you're suggesting :)

Comment: Unfortunately I'm at work at the moment and can't take the time to write it, nor do I have the means to test since I don't have Unity on this workstation, but when I get home sure! I'd love to. I love writing HLSL as it is probably the closest to C as I'll ever get lol.